# Syntax erro, Trigger Mysql executada pelo php

Tags: php, mysql, trigger, syntax-error

Alguém poderia por gentileza me dizer onde estou errando na criação da minha trigger

Trigger

```
$sql = "DELIMITER $$
                CREATE TRIGGER produtos_movto_insert AFTER INSERT ON produtos_movto
                            FOR EACH ROW
                            BEGIN
                                IF NEW.prmv_maismenos = '+' THEN
                                    UPDATE produtos SET prod_qte_estoque = (prod_qte_estoque + NEW.prmv_qte) WHERE idprodutos = NEW.prmv_idprodutos;         
                                END IF;

                                IF NEW.prmv_maismenos = '-' THEN
                                    UPDATE produtos SET prod_qte_estoque = (prod_qte_estoque - NEW.prmv_qte) WHERE idprodutos = NEW.prmv_idprodutos;
                                END IF;                                         
                END
                $$";
```

Erro

```
Erro: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER produtos_movto_insert AFTER INSERT ON produtos' at line 1
```

Esta sendo armazenada em uma variável php e é executada pelo php

Comment: vc pode dizer qual é o erro, a linha?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Editei a pergunta e coloquei o erro la

Comment: Ando enferrujado, mas creio que falte um `;` após o `END` e antes do `$$` (no final da sintaxe)?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Acabei de colocar o `;` no ultimo `END` porem o erro persistiu